# iPhone SDK - WebView activity indicator

Tags: iphone, sdk, view, uiwebview, uitabbar

I have a big problem with the UIWebView in iPhone SDK.
I have a TabBarApplication with one WebView on each Tab (except the first).

Because it takes quiet a while to load the views I'd like to show an activity indicator.

Here is the code I'm using in order to do that:

```
-(void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *) portal {
```

[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
 }

```
-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *) portal{
 [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO; 
}
```

It doesn't work this way... My WebView in the first tab is called "portal", that's why I entered it above, but the same problem exists if I use WebView.

Any ideas? Can't be true that this is soooo difficult.
I'm searching for a clue quiete a while now and found nothing which helped me to build such a (think it's easy) activityindicator.

Thanks a lot for your effort!

Greets from Germany
Tobias

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I typically use a UIActivityIndicatorView.

If you have a Navigation Controller on top of the web view it works perfectly:

```
-(void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *) portal {
UIActivityIndicatorView *actInd = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite];
UIBarButtonItem *actItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:actInd];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = actItem;

[actInd startAnimating];
[actInd release];
[actItem release];
}
```

To get rid of the indicator:

```
-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *) portal{
 self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil;
}
```

If you aren't using a Navigation Controller then I would simply use either the larger style, UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge OR place the view on top of a dark semi-transparent view on the screen and then remove them on load finish.

Comment: Thanks for your fast help!
The activityIndicator does not shop up in my App :(
Do you have any ideas?
I just copy and paste it exactly the way you postet it.

Is there a problem with my TabBar?

Comment: Well that code was if you had a UINavigationController that your controller witht he webview was inside (meaning you would have a nav bar at the top). If you don't then you would need to add the Activity Indicator to another view, [portal addSubview:actInd] for instance. What is your controller scheme? UITabBarController > ??? > UIWebView

Comment: Ahh, I see.

I have created a TabBar based Application and just droped the webviews in each element.
Each Tab has it's own controller for the webview.

Hope you understand what I mean? I'm completely new to Objective C and iPhone SDk...

Thanks so much for your help!

PS.
My Code now looks like this:
[code]
- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *) portal {
 UIActivityIndicatorView *actInd = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
 [portal addSubview:actInd];
 [actInd startAnimating];
 [actInd release];
}[/code]

Comment: So the view is showing up? So you know you'll have to maintain a pointer to the ActivityIndicator if you want to remove it in the didFinishLoad method.

Comment: The WebView is showing up but the ActivityIndicator Subview doesn't.
It seems like the App does not launch the DidStartLoad method, because it didn't worked with my NetworkActivityIndicator, too.

Comment: Where are you putting the webview delegate methods? Make sure whatever controller or object you put them in is set as the delegate of the UIWebView.

Comment: Can't imagine it's so hard to add an activityindicator....
Would you mind having a look at my App?
Please send me an email to: ruhrpotts-proud[at]iszene.com